# Error with file_put_contents

Tags: php, file, file-upload, error-handling

When using this code:

```
<?php
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $file = "file.html";

    file_put_contents($file, $email . PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND);

    include $file;
?>
```

I get this error:

```
PHP Warning:  file_put_contents(file.html): failed to open stream: Permission denied in G:\PleskVhosts\mydomain.com\test.php on line 5
```

What does that mean and how do I fix it?

Comment: That means you don't have the rights to write to `file.html`, and/or don't have the writes to add files to the directory the file's in.

Comment: it means you were *denied permission* when trying to write the file.

Comment: I own the domain and I own the file. Why would I be denied permission? How do I fix it?

Comment: Talk to your hard disk about it. Usually `chown` or `chmod` are convincing arguments.

Answer (score 0):

You can test it with this snippet.

```
if (file_exists($file)) {
  echo "File exists." . PHP_EOL;
}

if (is_writable($file)) {
  echo "File is writable." . PHP_EOL;
}

if (is_readable($file)) {
  echo "File is readable." . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Comment: It says "File exists. File is readable." How do I make it writable?

Comment: As you are on windows, the answer @mjwatts gave doesn't apply to you.
I'm not sure how to make it writeable in windows, but try right-clicking on the file and see if you can set some permissions.

Comment: Not sure if this applys to you, but you could try this http://www.wikihow.com/Change-File-Permissions-on-Windows-7

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter if you own the domain, the file, or the computer it sits on - the fact is that the user who's trying to access the file does not have permissions.

In a terminal run `ls -la` in that directory and you will then see owner and group for this file, check that they are right.

If in doubt run `chmod 777 your_file.html` which will make it readable, writable, etc.

Comment: What is a terminal? Is that my web browser? How do I run those things?

Comment: I missed the fact you're using windows, so I can't help there. Maybe try using an ftp program to view the file on your host and that should be able to show you permissions and owner for the file?